# Typescript using multiple definitions

Tags: typescript

In React Native, I have a component that accepts an `item` prop. It can be of either type `Business` or `Product`.  a `Business` object has a `name` prop, but `Product` doesn't.
If I define `item` TS as `Business | Product`, I can only access props that are common for both definitions. I want to check if I have `item.name` but it's giving me `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Business | Product'`
What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Are they classes or interfaces?

Comment: interfaces. As in `export type Business = {  id: string; name: string; ...}`

Comment: You're looking for a custom Type Guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to create a custom [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). For example:

```
function isBusiness(item: Business | Product): item is Business {
  return (item as Business).name !== undefined;
}
```

When you will use this `isBusiness` function inside a `if` statement, Typescript will know that item is of type `Business` if true or `Product` if false.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you.